# Finding Sequence of Polynomials Whose Existence is Guaranteed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I'm interested in knowing whether we can find a sequence of polynomials (thanks to [Stone-Weierstras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)) that converges to the [Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) function on some random interval (for instance, [-2 , 2]. The sequence should be designed such that the degree of accuracy is monotone increasing, and such that the sequence converges to the Weierstrass function.

Can this be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: Well you know that such a sequence *exists*.  Is there some reason why you want an explicit formula?  And why the Weierstrass function in particular?  "Most" continuous functions are nowhere differentiable and they all look more or less alike.   If you are a huge fan of continuous, nowhere differentiable functions then you need this monster:  https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-12670-8

Comment: Interestingly enough, the first chapter of that book has been retracted by the publisher because of a claimed similarity with this article:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=A.%C2%A0Kucharski%2C%20Math%E2%80%99s%20beautiful%20monsters%3B%20how%20a%20destructive%20idea%20paved%20the%20way%20to%20modern%20math.%20Nautilus%20Q.%20%2811%29%20%282014%29
The book's authors disagree with the retraction.

Comment: @martycohen  My PDF file for the book includes that chapter with a watermark "RETRACTED CHAPTER" on each page.  Still readable though.  I have never seen that before.  There is a footnote explaining "...been retracted by the request of the Editor, because portions of the text are duplicated without permission from a previously published article by Adam Kucharski."  How, otherwise, do two mathematicians write a historical chapter without a lot of copying?  History is hard!

Comment: @B.S.Thomson The reason I want to do so is to make an animation with the polynomials converging to it. I guess I can just show a simpler function where an explicit function exists, and show the graph of the Weierstrass function and I will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Federico  Fake it.  Remember that any continuous function (including the W function) has a graph that is pixel-for-pixel identical with a polynomial.  So just hand draw a sequence of "vaguely smooth" functions that gets close to the W function picture.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson This is a great idea